# C# Init setters don't work on class records

Tags: c#, record, init

I'm trying to use the init setters on a regular record, and they don't seem to work. But when I add the word "struct" to make it a record struct it works fine. Is this intended? It seems weird.

It doesn't seem to be a visual glitch because the build fails because of it, and restarting visual studio makes no difference. Adding empty brackets also doesn't help.

[image: Error when using record's init setters]

Comment: You are actually using the setter twice and the compiler prevents this because of immutability. You need to use positional arguments `new Record(arg1, arg2);`

Comment: The record constructor requires you pass the values as arguments to it, not as init-block, to initialize the instance.

Comment: Please don't post error details in image links. Your question should contain both the code and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to use the init setters on a regular record, and they don't seem to work.

You're using a Primary Constructor syntax on your record, and as with any class constructor, any time you use the `new` keyword to create an instance (as opposed to `with` syntax) you need to provide values to the constructor. The fact that you could then also initialize that value via initializer syntax is just an artifact of the fact that the primary constructor's argument is also an `init` property.

> But when I add the word "struct" to make it a record struct it works fine. Is this intended?

Yes. The reason that this changes when making your record a `struct` is that C# has different rules for `struct`s in general. For example, if you never initialize a field that's a struct, it will just get initialized automatically to a state where all its fields are set to their default values. This is basically the `struct` equivalent of `null`, and the same thing will happen if you initialize any struct variable using the `default` keyword.

Also for `struct`s, C# always allows you to use the `new` keyword as if calling a public default (no-argument) constructor for a struct: if no such constructor exists, it will behave the same as if you'd used `default`. So even though you're declaring a primary constructor, you're allowed to use syntax that ignores the presence of that constructor.

Comment: Strictly speaking, structs *don't* have an implicit default constructor. That member doesn't exist, it's not part of the type. The compiler allows the syntax to be identical to `default(T)` in that case as there's no constructor to call. Now with C# 10, you *can* define a default constructor explicitly, but the compiler doesn't generate one for you if you don't explicitly define one, unlike classes. And when you define a default constructor explicitly in C# 10, `new MyStruct()` and `default(MyStruct)` are different.

Comment: [example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLTJguBjGrcD2CyANDCAJYA2JAJiANQA+AAgEwCMAsAFAsDMAAgxZcggMrceAb14BfXrwHDMOGBLa9ZPQbsHLxbABQBKXnsHaLCnjaVD2ggMJbze5SwAsggGKm3ulYWepLCHIIAvIIAdhAA7hIcpgDcAcGGwmyRMfEaKWk2ckA)

Comment: In that example, `S1` has no parameterless `.ctor` member and is initialized using `initobj S1`, whereas `S2` has a parameterless `.ctor` member and is initialized using `call instance void S2::.ctor()`.

Comment: @madreflection: Thanks for that clarification. I've updated my answer. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes. I believe that represents things accurately. But because you didn't mention default constructors on structs in C# 10, I'm not going to delete comments. It's important to be aware that the difference exists now.